# Access denied when writing file to newly created folder

Tags: php

I am trying to create a new file to a folder created in the same .php file, but when the program reaches the write phase it says that folder access is denied.

I am on Windows 10

```
<?php 
$data['itemName']= "wrist watch";
$data['pid']=1;
$data['price']=10;
$data['description']= "This is a wrist watch";
$directoryName = './ProductPages/'.$data['itemName'];
$tpl_file="viewProd.php";
//Check if the directory already exists.
if(!is_dir($directoryName)){
    //Directory does not exist, so lets create it.
    mkdir($directoryName, 0777, true);
}
//if exists exit
//else{
//  echo '<script src="itemAddfail.js"></script>';

//}

$placeholders=array("{itemName}","{price}","{description}","{pid}");

$tpl=file_get_contents($tpl_file);

$new_member_file = str_replace($placeholders, $data, $tpl);

$html_file_name = $data['itemName'].".html";
$fp = fopen($directoryName, "w"); 
fwrite($fp, $new_member_file); 
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: You are trying to fopen the directory, not a file within the directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to do this:

```
...
$html_file_name = $data['itemName'].".html";
$fp = fopen($directoryName. "/" . $html_file_name, "w"); // concatenate folder name and HTML file name
...
```